# Conda Colab Error Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed InvalidVersionSpec: Invalid version '4.19.112+':empty version component

Tags: deep-learning, anaconda, conda, google-colaboratory, miniconda

Browser: Google Chrome latest

I followed this [Conda + Google Colab](https://towardsdatascience.com/conda-google-colab-75f7c867a522) article to setup conda in colab which was **working perfectly a few days ago.**

After that, I tried to set up [FairMOT](https://github.com/ifzhang/FairMOT)
By running these commands

```
!conda create -n FairMOT --yes
!conda activate FairMOT --yes
!conda install  pytorch==1.2.0 torchvision==0.4.0 cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch --yes
```

Now, This is the error output I received.

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda deactivate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.


Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

InvalidVersionSpec: Invalid version '4.19.112+': empty version component


CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.


Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

InvalidVersionSpec: Invalid version '4.19.112+': empty version component
```

[Notebook Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AHxaa2ipKvfmshzBdZQhvhRwEFZ-PCvV?usp=sharing)

Comment: The version `'4.19.112+'` refers to the Linux version, which you can find typing `!cat /proc/version` in your Colab. This does not solve the issue at hand but might be a good place to look for. Use the option  `--verbose` when running `!conda create` and you should see the offending file, which in my case is:  `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/version.py`. Any updates on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a quick-fix that works. I do not recomend this as a long-term solution.

Change the contents of the file that raises the `InvalidVersionSpec` error. In my case this is the file **/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/version.py**. You can get the location of this file for your case using `!conda create your_env --verbose`. (Note that one file generates the exception, but another one raises `InvalidVersionSpec`, go for the latter).

Following are the lines of code of our interest:

```py
# imports...
# Class definitions...

@with_metaclass(SingleStrArgCachingType)
class VersionOrder(object):
    # ...

    def __init__(self, vstr):
        # ...

                # The following line is raising the Exception:
                if not c:
                    raise InvalidVersionSpec(vstr, "empty version component")
```

Add the following in the first line of the `__init__` method of class `VersionOrder`:

```py
      if isinstance(vstr, str) and vstr == '4.19.112+':
          vstr = '4.19.112'
```

So it looks like this:

```py
# imports...
# Class definitions...

@with_metaclass(SingleStrArgCachingType)
class VersionOrder(object):
    # ...

    def __init__(self, vstr):
      if isinstance(vstr, str) and vstr == '4.19.112+': # Added code
          vstr = '4.19.112'
        # ...

                # The following line is raising the Exception:
                if not c:
                    raise InvalidVersionSpec(vstr, "empty version component")
```

What is happening is basically eliminating the `+` from the version name. It creates the error, so it might be a typo of the version spec, or a bug in handling this syntax by conda's `VersionOrder` class. I propose this solution as a quickfix in order to avoid side-effects on both files.

#### How to do this easily in Colab

Print the contents of your file */usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/version.py* using cat:

```sh
!cat /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/version.py
```

Copy the contents using the clipboard and paste them in a new code cell that starts with the magic command `%%file my_new_version_file.py`:

```
%%file my_new_version_file.py

# Paste your clipboard here
```

Next, add the previously mentioned code in this new cell and run it.
This will create a file **my_new_version_file.py** with the contents of the cell.

Then move the generated file into the path of the original one using `shutil`:

```py
import shutil
shutil.move('my_new_version_file.py', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/version.py')
```

Comment: Made my day! Thanks a lot!
You could change `%%file my_new_version_file.py` to `%%file new_version_file.py` to make it consistent with the filename used further down.